# OpenAI API error: "Module 'openai' has no attribute 'ChatCompletion', did you mean 'Completion'?"

Tags: python, openai-api, chatgpt-api, chat-gpt-4

I can't seem to figure out what the issue is here, I am running version 0.28.1:

[image]

from what I have read I should be using ChatCompletion rather than Completion as that's what gpt-4 and 3.5-turbo supports.

```
response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
    prompt=question,
    temperature=0,
    max_tokens=3700,
    top_p=1,
    frequency_penalty=0,
    presence_penalty=0,
    stop=None,
    model="gpt-4",
)
```

Looking at other answers I can also tell you that my file isn't named openai.py or anything like that.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First of all, be sure you have an up-to-date OpenAI package version.**

If not, upgrade the OpenAI package.

Python:

```
pip install --upgrade openai
```

NodeJS:

```
npm update openai
```

The code posted in your question above has a mistake. **The [Chat Completions API](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/gpt/chat-completions-api) doesn't have the `prompt` parameter as the [Completions API](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/gpt/completions-api) does.** Instead, it has the `messages` parameter. See the official [OpenAI documentation](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/chat/create?lang=python).

Try the following:

```
import os
import openai
openai.api_key = os.getenv("OPENAI_API_KEY")

completion = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
  model = "gpt-4",
  messages = [
    {"role": "system", "content": "You are a helpful assistant."},
    {"role": "user", "content": "Hello!"}
  ]
)

print(completion.choices[0].message)
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, check your version of the openai python module:

```
PS C:\demo> pip show openai
Name: openai
Version: 1.0.1
Summary: Client library for the openai API
```

References for the python library:
https://platform.openai.com/docs/libraries/python-library
https://github.com/openai/openai-python

The newer versions of the OpenAI Python API library (1.01) no longer support the ChatCompletion attribute. Following is what happens.

The code:

```
import openai
from dotenv import dotenv_values
config = dotenv_values(".env")
openai.api_key = config["OPENAI_API_KEY"]

reply = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
    model="gpt-4",
    messages=[
        {"role": "user", "content": "Hello world"}
    ]
)

print(reply.choices[0].message.content)
```

The result:

```
PS C:\demo> python .\temp.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\demo\temp.py", line 7, in <module>
    reply = openai.ChatCompletion.create(

           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

**AttributeError: module 'openai' has no attribute 'ChatCompletion'**

---

You must now import the class named OpenAI from a openai module:

```
# import os module and OpenAI class from the openai module
#import os
from openai import OpenAI

# no longer necessary as the client object defaults to 'os.environ.get("OPENAI_API_KEY")'
# get the OpenAI API key from OPENAI_API_KEY environment variable
# openai.api_key = os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"]

# instantiate a client object for interacting with the OpenAI API
client = OpenAI(
    # if no api_key argument is explicitly provided, the OpenAI class will attempt to retrieve the 
    # API key from an environment variable called OPENAI_API_KEY
    # Defaults to os.environ.get("OPENAI_API_KEY")
    # Otherwise use: api_key="Your_API_Key",
)

reply = chat_completion = client.chat.completions.create(
    model="gpt-4",
    messages=[{"role": "user", "content": "Hello world"}]
)
              
print(reply.choices[0].message.content)
```

---

The new OpenAI API client has a chat attribute with a method completions.create(), which is used to interact with OpenAI's chat-based models like gpt-4
So... all that code actually comes down to this:

```
from openai import OpenAI
client = OpenAI( )
reply = chat_completion = client.chat.completions.create(
    model="gpt-4",
    messages=[{"role": "user", "content": "Hello world"}]
)             
print(reply.choices[0].message.content)
```

Isn't that nicer anyway? Hope that helps!

Comment: client.chat.completion has an error ----------- AttibuteError : Chat object has no attribute 'completion', My openai version is 1.2.3

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if you want to use the older Completions API, you can just tell pip to install a version less than version 1 like this:

```
pip install "openai<1"
```